# Kinect SimpleOpenNI and Processing Range

Tags: range, kinect, processing, openni

I need to find a way to have the kinect only recognize objects in a certain Range. The problem is that in our setup there will be viewers around the scene who may disturb the tracking. Therefore I need to set the kinect to a range of a few meters so it won't be disturbed by objects beyond that range. We are using the SimpleOpenNI library for processing.

Is there any possibility to achieve something like that in any way?

Thank you very much in advance.

Matteo

Comment: This should be simple enough, but it also depends on your setup. Would this be more like a multi touch setup (kinect above a surface, next to a projector) or anything like that ?

Comment: You can use the coordinates of the Torso to discharge people that are not within a certain x and z ranges. In this way you limit your computations to the person who is at a certain distance from the sensor (z coordinate) and at the center of the scene (xcoodinate). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the user's centre of mass(CoM) which retrieves a x,y,z position for a user without skeleton detection:

[image: OpenNI user CoM]

Based on the z position you should be able to use a basic if statement for your range/threshold.

```
import SimpleOpenNI.*;

SimpleOpenNI context;//OpenNI context
PVector pos = new PVector();//this will store the position of the user
ArrayList<Integer> users = new ArrayList<Integer>();//this will keep track of the most recent user added
float minZ = 1000;
float maxZ = 1700;

void setup(){
  size(640,480);
  context = new SimpleOpenNI(this);//initialize
  context.enableScene();//enable features we want to use
  context.enableUser(SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_PROFILE_NONE);//enable user events, but no skeleton tracking, needed for the CoM functionality
}
void draw(){
  context.update();//update openni
  image(context.sceneImage(),0,0);
  if(users.size() > 0){//if we have at least a user
    for(int user : users){//loop through each one and process
      context.getCoM(user,pos);//store that user's position
      println("user " + user + " is at: " + pos);//print it in the console
      if(pos.z > minZ && pos.z < maxZ){//if the user is within a certain range
        //do something cool 
      }
    }
  }
}
//OpenNI basic user events
void onNewUser(int userId){
  println("detected" + userId);
  users.add(userId);
}
void onLostUser(int userId){
  println("lost: " + userId);
  users.remove(userId);
}
```

You can find more explanation and hopefully useful tips in these [workshop notes](http://ruairiglynn.co.uk/teaching/index.php?title=Kinect_Workshop_2012_Tutorial3) I posted.